# DotNetNuke Journal Module - User Profile Layout Discrepancy Between English and Italian Versions

Tags: dotnetnuke, journal, dnn9

I'm encountering an issue with my DotNetNuke(Verison 9) website where the layout of the user profile differs between the English and Italian language versions. Specifically, when accessing the user profile on the English version of the website, using the 'Journal' module, the layout appears as expected with all icons visible. However, when accessing the user profile on the Italian version, the layout is altered and some icons, images are missing.[image]

English User Profile Link: https://www.gw-360.com/en-us/Activity-Feed/userId/62
Italian User Profile Link: https://www.gw-360.com/it-it/Activity-Feed/userId/62

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this discrepancy and ensure consistent user profile layouts across different language versions of the website. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like different templates in the Journal module and different settings in the Console module. I would start to compare these.

Comment: Settings are the same on both profile pages, could you tell me where to check template?

Comment: As already answered here: [dnncommunity.org Forums](https://dnncommunity.org/forums/using-dnn/admin-and-config/dotnetnuke-journal-module-user-profile-layout-discrepancy-between-english-and-italian-versions/) it was my fault - there are no template settings in the Journal module. My mistake, sorry for that.  I must have confused it with something else.